# Multiple custom filters in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a multi check box application which requires me to have multiple filters. I have been unable to use multiple filters even if I try to hard code an array to filter on. Here is an example I have created to try to make this work.

[Working Example](http://codepen.io/Yin_Master/pen/AEocu/)

**HTML MARKUP:**

```
 <body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">


     <div ng-repeat="item in data.sessions | IndustryFilter :  data.sessions.industry  ">
         {{item.id}}
     </div>
 </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module("app", [])
.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope, MatchedFilterList) {

$scope.data = {"sessions": [{ 
"id": "a093000000Vhzg7AAB",
"industry": ["Automovtive"],
"sessionName": "Keynote",
},
{ 
"id": "a093000000zg7AAB",
"industry": ["Automovtive", "Retail"],
"sessionName": "Keynote2",
},
{ 
"id": "a093er000f00zg7AAB",
"industry": ["Automovtive", "Retail", "Consumer Goods"],
"sessionName": "Keynote3",
}                      
]}; 
}).filter("IndustryFilter", function (MatchedFilterList) {
return function () {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(MatchedFilterList.industry, function (item) {

    filtered.push(item);

    });
    console.log("Filter: Filter " + filtered)
    return filtered;
};
})
.factory("MatchedFilterList", function(){
 var matchedFilterList = {};
 matchedFilterList.industry = {
 "Automotive": "Automotive",
 "Retail" : "Retail"
 };
 return matchedFilterList;
});
```

Comment: What result do you get?  Are there any error messages?

Comment: No errors. I know what is wrong now. The angular filter return function should have a parameter the comes from the data object because this is a real object to filter upon. Now that I know it is filtering I have to write the proper filter logic which is now my new problem

Comment: Feel free to write up your answer in the box below.